# Ruby, Delete elements (slices) from a multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array, slice

(Pretty new with Ruby) 
I can remove a block of elements from a single-dimensional array

```
array1D = Array.new(6){|i| i*i}
array1D.slice!(2,2) #=> [1, 16, 25]
len = array1D.length #=> 4
```

However,

`Array(arrayd3d[0][0]).slice!(30000,8880)`

on arrayd3d[1][1][38884],

I still get

```
len = array3D.length #=> 38884
```

1) What I'm doing wrong?

2) How can I delete the same block of elements (30000,8880) from all
arrayd3d[1..nDim1][1..nDim2]?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the arrayd3d that you are trying to slice?  It's not clear to me from the question precisely what you are trying to achieve through slice.

Comment: You need to: 1) display an array `arrayd3d`, without reference to how it was created. 2) display a Ruby object that identifies the elements to be "sliced". 3) show the desired return object, which appears to be an array as well. One possibility for #1 is `arrayd3d = [[[1,2],[3,4]], [[5,6],[7,8]]]`. For #2 I'm *guessing* you want something like `remove = [3,6]`, which would result in the desired return value being `[ [[1,2],[4]], [[5],[7,8]]]`. If that's what you want you need to explain what you want when `arrayd3d = [[[1,6],[3,4]], [[3,6],[7,8]]]` and `remove = [3,6]`.

Comment: `array3d` is of a certain class I have no control over. Upon creation, `array3d` gets assigned a data structure. Inspecting it, `arrayd3d.length #=> dim1`,`arrayd3d[0].length #=> dim2`, `arrayd3d[0][0].length #=> nSamples`. For example,`arrayd3d[0][0][0] #=> `, `arrayd3d[0][0][1] #=> 5`, etc. I need to remove a block of elements, at a known location `arrayd3d[0][0][i1..i2]`. To make it more exciting, I need to remove the same same block from all `dim1` and `dim2`, `arrayd3d[0..dim1-1][0..dim2-1][i1...i2]`. It does not have to be with `.slice!`, anything is acceptable. @tgmerritt

Answer (score -1):

[slice!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-slice-21) returns the deleted object:

```
a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.slice!(1)     #=> "b"
a               #=> ["a", "c"]
```

In general in ruby we prefer not to alter the original object unless we're looking for some particular performance gain (very very rare, eg maybe you want to reduce the memory consumption of a very large array before moving on).

That's the reason for the exclamation symbol (`!` aka `bang`) which usually indicates some destructive behaviour.

Please consider using the non-bang version instead.

```
Array.new(6){ |i| i*i }
y = array1D.slice(2,2)

or

def some_method(input_array)
  input_array.slice(2,2)
end

x = Array.new(6){ |i| i*i }
y = some_method(x)
```

This way your code becomes more predictable as you're not altering the value of your arguments.

Comment: How does the answer address the multi-dimensional aspect of the question?  It looks like you're simply explaining how slice! functions in Ruby, which is not the question asked.

Comment: However I agree with the above, I need to remove data blocks that are considered irrelevant (according to a certain criterion). This has to be in the original array (object of a certain class) and return it back. An alternative would be to assign the complete 1D subarray to another 1D array, remove the data blocks from the latter and then replace the original subarray by the modified one. Got no idea how to implement this in Ruby though. @Swoveland